# transform: scale respects old height and width

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Okay so I have a few images that I want to fit side by side but I need to use scale to make them smaller as there are other properties(not shown here) that need to scale down with the whole image. The problem is, is that when I go to scale the images down they are still respecting their old height and width. Even when you inspect them it shows their correct size but there is just white space in between my photos. 
Here is the HTML

```
<div class="images">
  <img class="image-scaled" src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img class="image-scaled" src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
  <img class="image-scaled" src="http://fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.images {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image-scaled {
  transform: scale(.5);
}
```

And here is the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/justcald/t3teud7f/1/

What I want is to center all of the images so the sides are all touching and there isn't so much white space. But I can't seem to figure anything out.

Comment: That's what `transform` does...it's a *visual* change...not an actual dimension change,

Comment: Ahhhh.. Thank you! That makes me rethink my whole approach.